# Is there a way to read the values property of a PySimpleGUI combobox?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have created a PySimpleGUI combo box with code which simplifies down to:

```
combo_list = ['Choice 1', 'Choice 2']    
layout = [[sg.Combo(combo_list, default_value=combo_list[0], key='-COMBO-', enable_events=True)]]
```

The user is able to add items to the drop-down list, and when he quits the app, I save the updated combo_list so that it can be used when the program is next run. At the moment I am doing this by adding any new entries made by the user, to my combo_list array. But is there a way to simply read back the updated parameter 'values' from the Combo element itself rather than having to shadow it by updating the combo_list array?

There is no problem reading back the value that the user has chosen using `window['-COMBO-'].get()`, but in spite of checking the PySimpleGUI docs, and more generally, I have not been able to find a way to read the list of values. If this is not possible, I will continue to update the combo_list array whenever the user adds an item. But it would be good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get
>
> Returns the current (right now) value of the Combo. DO NOT USE THIS AS THE NORMAL WAY OF READING A COMBO! You should be using values from your call to window.read instead.  Know what you're doing if you use it.

To get the `combo_list` of a Combo element, you can get it by tkinter code, like `window['-COMBO-'].widget['values']`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

combo_list = ['Choice 1', 'Choice 2']
layout = [[sg.Combo(combo_list, default_value=combo_list[0], key='-COMBO-', enable_events=True)]]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)
    print(window['-COMBO-'].widget['values'])

window.close()
```

```py
-COMBO- {'-COMBO-': 'Choice 2'}
('Choice 1', 'Choice 2')
```

Comment: Of course! Great answer - thanks. But widget needs to be capitalised:  print(window['-COMBO-'].Widget['values'])

Comment: Maybe you need to upgrade your PySimpleGUI from Github, refer https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#upgrading-from-github-using-pysimplegui

Comment: I upgraded PySimpleGUI from 4.57.0 to 4.60.5, and it does indeed now accept 'widget' in lower case. Thanks for the heads-up.